# How to allow a line of Java Code in a Xtext grammar

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

**Question:** I would like to have an execution block in my grammar, which allows any valid java line (or just any line, this would be okay, too) within its borders:

```
Execution:
  {Execution} 'execute {'
    (lines+=(JavaLine | Referral))*
  '}'
;

Referral:
    inReferal | outReferal
;

inReferal:
    name=ID '<=' port=ID
;

outReferal:
    name=ID '=>' port=ID
;

JavaLine:
    {JavaLine}(words+=ID)* ';' // this doesn't fit quite its needs, no . - { etc allowed
;
```

This is the relevant part of the grammar, how would I have to build JavaLine in order to get any line?

**Bonus Question**: I have other rules like OutPort or Parameter, how can I prevent them from being used within my execute block? (I get syntax highlighted out keywords within my java lines)

```
Model:
    stages+=Stage*;

Stage:
    'stage' name=ID (('implements' interfaces=List)? & ('extends' extension=ID)?) '{'
       lines+=StageItems*
    '}';

List: items+=ID (',' items+=ID)*;

StageItems: 
  InPort | OutPort | Parameter | Execution
;

Parameter:
    'param' type=ID name=ID
;

InPort:
    'in' type=ID name=ID
;

OutPort:
    'out' type=ID name=ID
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
Execution:
  content=JAVA_LINE
;

terminal JAVA_LINE:
  'execute'
    '{'->'}' // TODO: this doesn't fit quite its needs
;
```

For the code generation I had to remove some content from the content string, but everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Java code is not organized into lines. Technically almost any line is acceptable as a Java source code, because you can put `/* */` multi-line comment in a Java source.

If you prescind from *line* concept, you can parse Java source using [Java Grammar (Java7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) or [Java Grammar (Java8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html) - that's quite a big work.

Perhaps easier if you only implement **Block** grammar ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html#jls-19-14)) - that represents an executable block in Java. That's less work.

If you want to allow one-liner Java code only (preserving the *line* concept), you can focus to **Statement** level, picking the allowed statement-types (e.g. no subclass definition, no labels, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I somehow import an existing java grammar? The only thing I would like to do is to copy the content in the execute block completely.

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:**

One possibility to define it as String instead of list words (with ID). You can later transform the string to Java Code in the generation process.

```
JavaLine:
    {JavaLine}(words=STRING)* ';'
;
```

**Second Question:**

If you use my suggestion for question one, the second problem should be obsolete.